# MySQL Workbench 8.0 - show errors?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-workbench

I am using mysql workbench 8.0.33 Community for Ubuntu 22.04. When a query encounters an error, I would like to see the system error messages. Currently, the GUI only displays a 'query interrupted' at the status bar (see below), and I have to go to /home/.mysql/workbench/log to open the .log text file to see what error that is.

[image]

Is there not a way to make the Workbench display the errors? I looked into View > Panels but all panels are enabled.

Thanks

Comment: **Exactly** which version of MySQL Workbench are you using? (I have `8.0.25` on my machine). Can you post a screenshot of the _entire_ MySQL Workbench window? Where is your Output pane? (Do you see the "Display output window" button in the right-side of the status-bar?)

Comment: updated the post with more info, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution didn't work for me on xubuntu 22.04. However, OP's workaround of using the log file sorted me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the row of 3 buttons in the top-right corner? Click the middle button to show the Output pane.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How could I have missed this...

Comment: @Ziqi _perceptual blindness_ happens to everyone